# How to redirect www to non www rule in AspNetCore 1.1 preview 1 with RewriteMiddleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Using the AspNetCore 1.1 bits and the new [RewriteMiddleware](https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite) I wrote something like this into the `Startup.cs` to handle www to non www redirect :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var options = new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRedirect("(www\\.)(.*)", "$1");

    app.UseRewriter(options);

    // Code removed for brevty
}
```

Since the [RedirectRule](https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite/Internal/RedirectRule.cs) only apply to the path and not the entire request uri, 
the regex does not match.

How can I redirect www to non www rule using the same approach ? I wouldn't like use the [IISUrlRewriteRule](https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite/Internal/IISUrlRewrite/IISUrlRewriteRule.cs).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`RewriteOptions` allows you add a custom rule implementation. As you identified, the pre-written rules don't support redirecting hostnames. However, this is not too hard to implement.

Example:

```
public class NonWwwRule : IRule
{
    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var req = context.HttpContext.Request;
        var currentHost = req.Host;
        if (currentHost.Host.StartsWith("www."))
        {
            var newHost = new HostString(currentHost.Host.Substring(4), currentHost.Port ?? 80);
            var newUrl = new StringBuilder().Append("http://").Append(newHost).Append(req.PathBase).Append(req.Path).Append(req.QueryString);
            context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(newUrl.ToString());
            context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

You can add this to the Rules collection on RewriteOptions.

```
        var options = new RewriteOptions();
        options.Rules.Add(new NonWwwRule());

        app.UseRewriter(options);
```

Comment: It does not work for my website,I am using ssl,I change http to https but still does not work.This is my website: https://ki-tap.com

Comment: I'd add only that if you're using NWebsec redirect validation then you need to add your own domain into the AllowedDestinations or it'll through an exception in live when redirecting from www to the domain. 
https://docs.nwebsec.com/en/4.1/nwebsec/Redirect-validation.html